# I have a PHP CodeIgniter Controller with name dashboard and this controller is in a admin named folder, How can i access that controller using url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have a PHP CodeIgniter Controller with name dashboard and this controller is in a admin named folder, i try to login in admin dashboard using url=>'admin/dashboard' but it show nothing and redirect me to login page.

```
 class Dashboard extends Admin_Controller {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('admin_model');
    }

    public function index() {

        $data['title'] = "Care Your Car";
        $employee_id = $this->session->userdata('employee_id');
        //total employee count
        $this->admin_model->_table_name = "tbl_employee"; //table name
        $this->admin_model->_order_by = "employee_id"; // order by
        $data['employee'] = $this->admin_model->get_by(array('status' => 1)); // get resutl
        $data['total_employee'] = count($this->admin_model->get()); // get resutl

        $data['subview'] = $this->load->view('admin/main_content', $data, TRUE);
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $data);
    }
```

### login model

```
<?php

class Login_Model extends MY_Model {

    protected $_table_name;
    protected $_order_by;
    public $rules = array(        
        'user_name' => array(
            'field' => 'email',
            'label' => 'Email',
            'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email'
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'Password',
            'rules' => 'trim|required'
        )
    );

    public function login() {
        //check user type

        $this->_table_name = 'tbl_employee_login';
        $this->_order_by = 'employee_login_id';
        $employee = $this->get_by(array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
             'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
            'activate' => 1
        ), TRUE);
        /*employee*/
        $this->_table_name = 'driver';
        $this->_order_by = 'driver_id';

        $driver = $this->get_by(array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
        ), TRUE);
        /*driver*/
        $this->_table_name = 'tbl_user';
        $this->_order_by = 'user_id';

        $admin = $this->get_by(array(
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                ), TRUE);
        if ($admin) {
            $data = array(
                'email' => $admin->email,
                'first_name' => $admin->first_name,
                'last_name' => $admin->last_name,
                'employee_id' => $admin->user_id,
                'loggedin' => TRUE,
                'user_type' => 1,
                'user_flag' => $admin->flag,
                'url' => 'admin/dashboard',
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        } elseif($employee) {

            if (count($employee)) {
                // Log in user
                $employee_id = $employee->employee_id;
                $this->_table_name = "tbl_employee"; //table name
                $this->_order_by = "employee_id";
                $user_info = $this->get_by(array('employee_id' => $employee_id), TRUE);

                $data = array(
                    'email' => $employee->email,
                    'employee_id' => $employee->employee_id,
                    'user_name' => $user_info->first_name . '  ' . $user_info->last_name,
                    'employee_login_id' => $employee->employee_login_id,
                    'loggedin' => TRUE,
                    'user_type' => 2,
                    'url' => 'employee/dashboard',
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            }
        }
        elseif($driver){
            $data = array(
                'email' => $driver->email,
                'drive_id' => $driver->driver_id,
                'name' => $driver->name,
                'loggedin' => TRUE,
                'user_type' => 3,
                'url' => 'driver/dashboard',
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
    }

    public function loggedin() {
        return (bool) $this->session->userdata('loggedin');
    }

    public function hash($string) {
        return hash('sha512', $string . config_item('encryption_key'));
    }

}
```

### Log in Controller

```
class Login extends MY_Controller {
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
}

public function index() {

    //$this->session->sess_destroy();
    $dashboard = $this->session->userdata('url');

    $this->login_model->loggedin() == FALSE || redirect($dashboard);

    $rules = $this->login_model->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        // We can login and redirect
        if ($this->login_model->login() == TRUE) {
            redirect($dashboard);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Username / Password combination does not exist');
            redirect('login', 'refresh');
        }
    }
    $data['title'] = "User Login";
    $data['subview'] = $this->load->view('login', $data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
}
```

{i wanna login into admin dashborad but i can not, when i try enter username and pasword in login form and press enter it show me login page again instead of dashboard please help me to fix it }

Comment: index.php removed from URL ?

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam i decelared it in $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; thats why i am using only admin/dashboard

Comment: show me the code of redirect

Comment: $admin = $this->get_by(array(
     'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                ), TRUE);
        if ($admin) {
            $data = array(
                'email' => $admin->email,
                'first_name' => $admin->first_name,
                'last_name' => $admin->last_name,
                'employee_id' => $admin->user_id,
                'loggedin' => TRUE,
                'user_type' => 1,
                'user_flag' => $admin->flag,
                'url' => 'admin/dashboard',
            );

Comment: i mean where is `redirect(` is written

Comment: i does not any redirect in login model but i do not know why  redirect me on login agian when i enter username and password

Comment: add whole code. instead of the image. Can't understand your issue

Comment: ok give me a few minute

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam now thats my code for login_model and dashboard Controller

Comment: `Admin_Controller` controller ??

Comment: there is no admin controller , only admin _model

Comment: so change it to `CI_Controller`

Comment: where i change it?

Comment: what are these `class Login extends MY_Controller {` this `class Login_Model extends MY_Model {` and `class Dashboard extends Admin_Controller {` are you ***Extending the core* of CodeIgniter controller**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150575/discussion-between-muhammad-ahmed-and-abdulla-nilam).